# Pandas column selection with coordinates

Tags: pandas, numbers, coordinates, col

I've got a pandas dataframe:

`A.loc[:,:,location]`

with `location = (x, y)`
with `x` and `y` numbers. When i try to select the columns:
`locations = (1, 2)` in:

`B = A.loc[:,:,location]`

It says: '[(1, 2)] is not in the columns.'
When i print the dataframe it clearly says that (1, 2) is in the minor axis.
Any idea how I can select these coördinate-like columns?

Answer (score 0):

It is not really clear what you want, at least to me, but maybe these could help:

```
# Select the first 3 columns
df.iloc[:,:3]

# Select the first cell down in the column named location
df.ix[0, 'location']

# Select all the location rows has the value of "(1,2)"
df[(df['location'] == '(1,2)')]
```

Comment: If you clarify what dou you want I can try to help you

Comment: .ix did the trick, did not know of that command. Thanks for the help!